# How to create a JS object representing a Car object that contains the business object and its graphical representation ( a jquery DOM element)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui

I'm currently developing some UI components with jquery and jquery UI and these graphical objects, lets say its a Car will have a graphical part and also a business object attached to it, that will be sent back and forth to the server, reflecting the current values of it upon resizing, moving, removing, etc from the browser.

Does anyone can please point me out how should i achieve this? Shall i create a javascript object that contains 2 objects inside, one representing the object with properties (width, height, weight, color) and other with the macthing Jquery object that represents this instance of the object in the DOM?

Can anyone point out an example and give a quick explanation what are the best practices/approach to achieve this representation?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You need to take a look at [Backbone](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone). It does exactly what you need.

Comment: Looks very confusing at a first sight... maybe it add a big learning curve... i'll check it out further! Thanks for your input